# how to improve performance of select

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written a procedure which takes several input parameters.
I need to validate the input.
If they are valid values they have to be present in the database table - attribute_values.
The problem is attribute_values table contains million records.
I am now supposed to improve the performance of select query.
For validating 1 input parameter I am doing something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO COUNT_VAR 
  FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUES A 
 WHERE A.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = input_paramater1;
IF COUNT_VAR = 1 THEN 
SELECT ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID INTO MYVAR1 
  FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUES A 
 WHERE A.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE =  input_paramater1; 
END IF; 

other_procedure(MYVAR1);
```

Any suggestions for improving performance of selecting from a table which contains a million  records.
Also out of count(*) and count(1) which is better.

Comment: basic sql rule of thumb: any field used in a decision context, e.g. a `where`, `order by`, `join`, or `group by` clause should have an index on it.

Comment: assume I am already having an index on it. Apart from that anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: Do you really need exactly one match, or at least one?  And COUNT(*) performs the same as COUNT(1).

Comment: What are the query plans for these two statements?  Are they actually using the index?  Why are you doing a `COUNT(*)` and then a separate query to get the value?  Do you have a reason to expect that is more efficient than just doing the `SELECT INTO` and catching an exception if that returns something other than 1 row?

Comment: Also, is the problem really the performance of this particular `SELECT` statement?  Or is the problem that this `SELECT` statement is called a very large number of times?  If so, is it possible to refactor the code so that you are using collections and doing `bulk collect` operations so that you're spending less time constantly swapping between the SQL and PL/SQL engines?

Comment: @Justin Cave - SELECT statement is called a very large number of times. It is not possible to use collections because all the values that I want to validate are in different rows of ATTRIBUTE_VALUES table.I think I can create a subblock and do just 1 SELECT INTO for a particular input paramater and catch NO_DATA_FOUND exception. (Currently I m checking count(*) then doing select into) so that will reduced the select statements by half. Also I will add an index

Comment: @DCookie I need at least 1 match.

Comment: Then your code is wrong. You are checking for exactly one match.

Comment: @DCookie is correct - if there can be more than one row in ATTRIBUTES_VALUES for a given value of ATTRIBUTE_VALUE then the `SELECT...INTO...` that attempts to retrieve ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID will fail with a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception if there is more than one row with the same ATTRIBUTE_VALUE. In this case, which ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID should be processed: any one of them at random, all of them, or none of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` followed by a `SELECT ID...`, both against the same table, I suggest you rework this logic as follows:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID
    INTO MYVAR1 
    FROM ATTRIBUTE_VALUES A 
    WHERE A.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = INPUT_PARAMETER1 AND
          ROWNUM = 1;

  COUNT_VAR := 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    COUNT_VAR := 0;
    MYVAR1 := NULL;
END;

OTHER_PROCEDURE(MYVAR1);
```

This helps two ways. First, in my experience `SELECT COUNT...` is *slow*, so I try to avoid it whenever possible. Second, this not only saves a second query but lets you take advantage of the standard exception handling built in to PL/SQL.

Share and enjoy.

**EDIT:** given OP's revelation (in comments to the question, above) that ATTRIBUTE_VALUES.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE is not unique I've updated the code above so that it will not fail if more than one row would be returned.

Answer (score 1):

For these queries, I would suggest an index:

```
create index attribute_values_attribute_value on attribute_values(attribute_value);
```

This should suffice for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

### 3 STEPS:

**1)** If possible partition the table.

**2)** Create Index as follows

```
CREATE INDEX idx1_attribute_values ON attribute_values(attribute_value, attribute_value_id);
```

**3)** Use the following coding style for better results

```
BEGIN
    SELECT attribute_value_id
      INTO myvar1
      FROM attribute_values a
     WHERE a.attribute_value = input_parameter1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN others THEN
    myvar1 := 0;    -- Handle the error codes accordingly
END;
```

If it still doesn't work, post the plan of the query.